# JQuery UI Tabs -clear page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a set of containers that are loaded in JQuery UI tabs each time I click on a search button. What I want to do is to clear the whole tab before I load anything in that. I tired the following but it didn't work.

```
$("#tab1").html("");
$("#tab2").html("");
```

Comment: Are you sure the IDs for the containers are really `tab1` and `tab2`?

Comment: yes, it says container is not defined. I even add a container inside that tab and check that out but both have the same error.

Comment: Could you post the part of the HTML where you define the tabs, as well as the part of the js where you call `$.tabs()`?

Comment: are you loading your tabs using jquery's ajax calls?

Comment: here is the code

<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
                <li><a style="font-size:small;" href="#tab1">T</a></li>
                <li><a style="font-size:small;" href="#tab2">G</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div align="center" id="tab1">
        <div id='ts'> ....</div> </div>

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a style="font-size: small;" href="#tab1">T</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-size: small;" href="#tab2">G</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div align="center" id="tab1">
            <div id='ts'>
                ....</div>
        </div>
</div>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="ClearTabs()" />




<script >
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
        function ClearTabs() {
            $("#tab1").html("");
            $("#tab2").html("");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Does the order matters? because I have my JS on header and the html is on body...

Comment: I have it on header too, but it really doesn't matters because you're cleaning on button's click and by that time your tabs are already loaded. You may want to check where are you calling  $("#tab1").html("");, you can post your whole html if you you want me to review it

Comment: I even changed the order.. and still have the same problem... that'd be nice if you take a look at my code.. here I uploaded my code.. but I may remove it later... http://www.cse.msu.edu/~khakpour/test/test.html

the code is not working as I just moved the main file to there... but you can take look at the code... thanks...

Comment: I tried your code with jQuery v1.6.1 + JQuery UI 1.8.12 and it clears it as it should, this is a small version of your page

Comment: <html> 
<head> 
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script language="javascript"> 
$(function() {
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
}); 
function Search() {
$("#tabs0").html("");
}
</script>  
</head>

Comment: <body> 
<input type="button" value="Search" OnClick="javascript:Search();"> 
<br> 
<div id="tabs"> 
 <ul> 
  <li><a style="font-size:small;" href="#tabs0">Time Series</a></li> 
  <li><a style="font-size:small;" href="#tabs1">Geo Analysis</a></li> 
 </ul> 
 <div align="center" id="tabs0"> 
  <div id='timeseries'> 
   <div id='timestamp' style='width: 1200px; height: 340px;'></div> 
   <br> 
   <div id='timestampR' style='width: 1200px; height: 340px;'></div> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>  
</body> 
</html>

Comment: I can avice you to use firebug plugin for firefox, it really helps you to debug your jquery code nice and easy, good luck!